# How to cancel cancellationtoken for the second time in C# project

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

There are two threads in my C# project; UI thread and BackgroundWorker.

In BackgroundWorker there are some work such as;

```
private void testBgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        while (!worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            // Do some work!
            token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(20000);
        }
    }
```

In UI thread;

```
// Some initialization for CancellationToken
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

// Click event listener of the button!
    private void testBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           testBgWorker.CancelAsync();
           tokenSource.Cancel();
        }
```

In UI thread, when user clicks the button, BackgroundWorker starts running. If user clicks the button for the second one, BackgroundWorker is cancelled. ***There is no problem for this cycle.***

However, when user clicks again after BackgroundWorker is cancelled, since IsCancellationRequested is true, thread does not wait in the line of token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(20000) and passed it to next line. **This is a problem!**

Cannot I use token multiple times? How do I make isCancellationRequested property of cancellationtoken to false again for the second cycle? or do I have to use new cancellationtoken?

Comment: You can use cancellation token multiple times, but you can cancel it only once. You need to create a new `CancellationTokenSource` for a fresh start. Why would you mix cancellation tokens with `BackgroundWorker` anyways? They're two completely different asynchronous techniques, which are hardly used together.

Comment: @Alex Skalozub When user hits the button, some process has to be run repeatedly in every 20 seconds. All process has to be done asynchronously. Also, when user hits the button again, this process should be stopped. Maybe, I can use Thread.Sleep(20000) instead of WaitOne method, but it induces waiting unnecessarily when user clicks the button to stop the process. If you recommend something for this, I am ready to listen to you :)

Comment: If you prefer a `BackgroundWorker` to task-based approach, then just create a `ManualResetEvent` which you set when cancelling your worker, and reset when restarting.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub I'll check ManualResetEvent mechanism to put into my code. Thanks a lot for your contribution!

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you're asking. As Alex says, you cannot reuse `CancellationTokenSource` once it's been cancelled. It can only be cancelled once. Period. Without a good [mcve] and a better description of what you want the code to do, it's difficult to know what it is you actually want to happen.

Comment: But it is a bad design to have a long-running `BackgroundWorker` task. More likely, what you should be doing is using `BackgroundWorker` to run each instance of the task, and use a `Timer` object to initiate each run. Clicking the button would then stop the timer, rather than having to interact with the `BackgroundWorker` task at all (i.e. the task wouldn't even need to be cancellable).